# How can I make backup files start with a dot to make them hidden? (not just tilde)

Tags: backup

By default, vim seems to save a backup file ending in a tilde (see [`:help backup`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#backup)). For example, when editing `foobar.txt`, a backup file `foobar.txt~` is saved. I would like to have it saved to `.foobar.txt~` instead. On Linux, a file starting with a dot is considered a hidden file.

I can't use the option [`backupext`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'backupext') because it only allows use to set an extension and not a prefix.

Comment: Consider using backupdir to keep your backups away from your source?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to keep all of Vim's backup and state files in their own directory:

```
set directory=$HOME/tmp/vim//
set backupdir=$HOME/tmp/vim//
set undodir=$HOME/tmp/vim//
```

The two slashes at the end are important to ensure names are unique:

*For Unix and Win32, if a directory ends in two path separators, the swap file name will be built from the complete path to the file with all path separators substituted to percent '%' signs. This will ensure file name uniqueness in the preserve directory.*
(`:help directory`)

It is possible to store these file in the current directory as well -- see the documentation `:help directory`.